# How can I access my old Magento Admin Panel?

Tags: magento-1, admin-panel

we recently launched a new website and in doing so have lost access to the old admin site.  Both sites are using Magento 1 and we used to access the old site on the following URL, https://www.alltank.co.uk/index.php/manage

Now that takes you to a 404 on the new site and I don't know how to get back to the new one?

New site is on AWS

Old site is on Freethought

Comment: Do both websites point to the same domain name?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend asking whoever did the migration to create a subdomain and put your old site on there.

archive.alltank.co.uk or whatever.

Although I'm assuming they've still got the old files and database.  You need to have a chat with the developer and/or host.

Answer (score 0):

if you need this only for temporary backend access, you can simply create `hosts` record on your pc:

on windows:

```
file:///C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts
```

for better management you can use `notepad++` , open hosts file and add this record:

```
## old_ip_address custom_domain_name
   1.2.3.4 www.oldalltank.co.uk
```

save it.

change your domain name in old magento and old server.

but if you need it for long time work, you can simply change your old base url to - IP ADDRESS.

```
http://1.2.3.4/
```